# Typescript error on prop types of stateless React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tslint

In my project, someone wrote the following lines of code, which result in a Typescript error:

```
export const MaskedField = asField(({ fieldState, fieldApi, ...props }) => 
    {
        const {value} = fieldState;
        const {setValue, setTouched} = fieldApi;
        const {
            forwardedRef,
            guide,
            icon,
            initialValue,
            keepCharPositions,
            maskRegEx,
            onBlur,
            onChange,
            placeholder,
            placeholderChar,
            ...rest
        } = props;
    }
}
```

First of all, Lint gives me a trailing comma error, but when I place one after `props`, I get another Typescript error that spreadoperators can't have a trailing comma.

Most importantly, I'm having errors on the fields of the `const {...} = props` variable, telling me `Property '...' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.`

Any idea on how to fix this quickly?

Comment: You don't say which linter you're using, and technically you have two questions here that should be asked separately. I've answered the prop typing question below.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use TypeScript then you need to provide type information so TS can do it's type checking thing.

At the moment you haven't provided any information about the props type, so it only knows it has an optional children prop. That's why it says: `Property '...' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.`

Here's an example from the excellent [React Redux TypeScript Guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#stateless-components---sfc) site by Piotrek Witek:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface SFCCounterProps {
  label: string;
  count: number;
  onIncrement: () => any;
}

export const SFCCounter: React.SFC<SFCCounterProps> = (props) => {
  const { label, count, onIncrement } = props;

  const handleIncrement = () => { onIncrement(); };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{label}: {count} </span>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrement}>
        {`Increment`}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Nice! The person who wrote the code apparently fixed this already in the way you suggested, but my tslint is still giving an error on the `...rest`, since it has no trailing comma. When I add the comma, Typescript gives me the error that spread operators can't have a trailing comma. Is there a way to fix this without disabling that rule on that line?

Comment: I don't know sorry, I don't like trailing commas, so I have them turned off in my TSLint config: `"trailing-comma": false`. It looks like that issue is an open bug at the moment: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4172 From the comments ... "Adding "esSpecCompliant": true to the rule's options object fixes this."